# in iOS sqlite getting insertion error for html strings

Tags: html, ios, sqlite

I am in the requirement of saving the html strings in SQLite Database. While running the `insert` query, I am getting a syntax error near the `style` tag of the HTML file.

Here is the code:

```
-(BOOL)insertAttendees{
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    NSString *insertSQL;
    BOOL var=NO;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //work only for the 1st event
        for (int i=0; i<[attendeeCount[0]integerValue];i++)
        {

           insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO ATTENDEE (A_NAME,A_IMAGE,A_EMAIL,A_PHONE,A_BIO) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",arrayOf_AName[0][i],arrayOf_AImage[0][i],arrayOf_AEmail[0][i],arrayOf_APhone[0][i],arrayOf_ABio[0][i]];

            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                var=YES;
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"sqlite insertion error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                var=NO;
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return var;
    }
    return var;
}
```

Comment: Show your error message for more clarification

Comment: And we can't help you fix the error in your code unless you share the code with us.

Comment: which is working if an not trying to insert arrayOf_ABio[0][i]] as not the html string

Comment: i think this is due to the special characters in html tagged string .so guys is there any good suggestion to overcome my scenario ?

Comment: By the way, your `arrayOf_AName[0][i]` syntax looks suspicious. Are these five arrays for whom the first object is, itself, and array of `[attendeeCount[0]integerValue]` items? If so, fine, but that looks really suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of issues here:

1. The root of the problem is that you're building your SQL using `stringWithFormat`, which you should not do. If your values contained a quotation mark in them (such as might be near your `style` tag in your HTML), your SQLite code would fail. Instead, you should:

   - Your SQL should use `?` placeholders (note, no quotation marks in the SQL, either):

     ```
     const char *insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO ATTENDEE (A_NAME,A_IMAGE,A_EMAIL,A_PHONE,A_BIO) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
     ```
   - Then you should then bind values with something like:

     ```
     if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [string UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK) {
         NSLog(@"%s: bind column 1 failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
     }
     ```

     where `string` is the `NSString` value you want to insert, and that second parameter (`1`, in the above example) is the index of the `?` placeholder that you're binding to the text value (where the leftmost placeholder has an index of one).
   - Only after you've called `sqlite3_bind_xxxx()` for each of the five `?` placeholders, then you can proceed by calling `sqlite3_step()`, etc.
2. A second problem is that you are not checking to see if `sqlite3_prepare_v2` succeeded or not. This is significant because the meaningful error messages you would have seen if you called `sqlite3_errmsg` immediately after the prepare statement failed is now lost. You're ignoring any potential prepare error, proceeding with `sqlite3_step` regardless, and so the meaningful error message will be replaced with one that effectively (but cryptically) says that you called `sqlite3_step` without first successfully calling `sqlite3_prepare_v2`.

   So, check to make sure if `sqlite3_prepare_v2` succeeded, and if it failed, check `sqlite3_errmsg` immediately before doing any other SQLite calls.
3. Once you solve the above two issues, you might consider optimizing your code a little. Notably, if you perform a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before all of your `INSERT` statements, and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` when you're done with all of your inserts, it will be much faster. If you're only inserting a couple of records it might not be observable, but if inserting a lot of records, the performance gain can be staggering.
4. As yet a further optimization, let's imagine that you addressed my above points (notably, eliminated `stringWithFormat` for the SQL and used `?` placeholders instead) and you had something like the following pseudo code (but obviously checking *all* of the sqlite3 function return values and handling errors properly):

   ```
   sqlite3_exec("begin transaction");

   for (i = 0; i < whatever; i++) {
       sqlite3_prepare(...);

       sqlite3_bind(...);
       sqlite3_bind(...);
       sqlite3_bind(...);
       sqlite3_bind(...);
       sqlite3_bind(...);

       sqlite3_step();

       sqlite3_finalize();
   }

   sqlite3_exec("commit transaction");
   ```

   Rather than preparing the same SQL many times, you can prepare it once, bind the values, perform the step, and then reset the bindings so you can do it again:

   ```
   sqlite3_exec("begin transaction");

   sqlite3_prepare(...);

   for (i = 0; i < whatever; i++) {

       sqlite3_bind(...);
       sqlite3_bind(...);
       sqlite3_bind(...);
       sqlite3_bind(...);
       sqlite3_bind(...);

       sqlite3_step();

       sqlite3_reset();
   }

   sqlite3_finalize();

   sqlite3_exec("commit transaction");
   ```

Personally, I'd suggest you focus on points 1 and 2 above, and only once you fix the fundamental problem should you contemplate the optimizations of points 3 and 4. Make sure you've got it working before you bother to optimize it.

Finally, I'd be remiss if I didn't point out that you really should contemplate the wonderful third-party [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) Objective-C wrapper around the SQLite C interface. When you write proper SQLite code, that is binding each value, checking each return code, etc., it gets unwieldy quickly. FMDB greatly simplifies your code.

Comment: Thank you Rob. This is helped me a lot.Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to insert HTML in sqlite database then replace all `"` with `\"` before executing the query.

*(You have't mentioned that whether you are replacing special characters or not).*

Suppose, you are doing this..

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE someColume = <div style="width:25px"></div>"
```

It will fail right after **style="** because sqlite will try to execute `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE someColume = <div style="`,

But if you replace `"` with `\"`, then your final query will look like this -

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE someColume = <div style=\"width:25px\"></div>"
```

Good luck.